# python database (sqlite3) and the treeview

Tags: python, sqlite, treeview

hi everyone i have a problem in my code i try to display my tables from the data base on the treeview but i can't i see this error "TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable"
might be because i have three table on my data base these is a part of my code :

```
tv=ttk.Treeview(root)
tv.place(x=24,y=335)
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('Treeview', rowheight=30)
tv.heading('#0',text="ID")
tv.column("#0",width=99)
tv.configure(column=('#Type','#Code','#Designation','#Prix achat'))
tv.heading('#Type',text="Type")
tv.heading('#Code',text="Code")
tv.heading('#Designation',text="Designation")
tv.heading('#Prix achat',text="Prix achat (DZA)")

cur=issam.tree_select()
for i in cur:
    tv.insert('','end','#{}'.format(i['ID']),text=i['ID'])
    tv.set('#{}'.format(i['ID']),'#Type',i['type'])
    tv.set('#{}'.format(i['ID']),'#Code',i['Code'])
    tv.set('#{}'.format(i['ID']),'#Designation',i['Designation'])
    tv.set('#{}'.format(i['ID']),'#Prix achat',i['pa'])
```

and these is the function in database file (in a class):

```
def tree_select(self):
    cursor=self.db.execute('SELECT * FROM poisson ')
    cur2=self.db.execute('SELECT * FROM plant')
    cur3=self.db.execute('SELECT * FROM materiel')
    return (cursor,cur2,cur3) #the problem is here
```

Comment: where is a question? you already pointed on problem: `tree_select` function returns tuple with 3 cursor objects, after it you are trying to iterate over tuples and extract key from cursor.

Comment: have you solved your problem or do you still need a help?

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable

You are trying to get item from cursor, that's why.

Function `tree_select` returns tuple of cursors:

```
tree_select() -> (<sqlite3.Cursor>, <sqlite3.Cursor>, <sqlite3.Cursor>)
```

After it you iterate over these cursors:

```
cur=issam.tree_select()
for i in cur:
    ...
```

After it you try to extract value by key from cursor(in each iteration step):

```
 tv.set('#{}'.format(i['ID']),'#Type',i['type'])    # i - is sqlite3.Cursor object
```

where `i` is a `sqlite3.Cursor` and fails with error: `'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable`

Here is a small example, how to extract values as from dictionary:

```
import sqlite3

def row2dict(cursor, row):
    result = dict()
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        result[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return result

db = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
db.row_factory = row2dict
cursor = db.cursor()

cursor.execute("select 1 as ID, 'john' as name")
row = cursor.fetchone()
print row['ID'], row['name']

cursor.close()
db.close()
```

Comment: so what i should do to display the three table on the treeview ? can you help me to rewrite the code please ?

Comment: @bouhenniissam, not now(today for me). if no one will help so I will try to help later(tomorrow for me). Why TK? Now browser applications are in trend ;)))